# Show that $G:[c,d]\to \mathbb R$ defined by $G(x)=\int_0^{f(x)}F(t)dt, x\in [c,d] $ is differentiable and $G'(x)=F\circ f(x) \cdot f'(x).$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Let $F$ be continuous on $[a,b].$ let $f:[c,d]\to \mathbb R$ be differential function satisfy $f([c,d])\subseteq [a,b].$  Show that $G:[c,d]\to \mathbb R$ defined by $G(x)=\int_0^{f(x)}F(t)dt, x\in [c,d] $ is differentiable and $G'(x)=F\circ f(x) \cdot f'(x).$

**My attempt**

$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ G(x+h)-G(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ \int_0^{f(x+h)}F(t)dt-\int_0^{f(x)}F(t)dt}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ \int_{f(x)}^{f(x+h)}F(t)dt}{h}$
I am not able to go beyond this.

Comment: Use chain rule and FOTC. Also, I think you mean $\int_a^{f(x)} F(t)\ dt$.

Comment: In fundamental theorem of calculus. We could say $\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)$. If there exists a differmntiable function F(x). right? What is the guarentee of existance of the differentiable function?@0XLR

Comment: No, you will be applying FOTC to another function: $H(y) = \int_a^y F(t)\ dt$. Then, $G = H \circ f$ and $H'(y) = ?$.

Comment: Okay. Let me see. Thank you for hints.